# What is lean way to add external pull-up in PCB?

Tags: esp32

I accidentally forgot to add external pull-up in EN pin.

PCB image: mine

Schematic: From the datasheet

So currently I can not upload firmware to my custom PCB, and can not test it.
Before reordering PCB, how can I make it work?

My initial thought is to solder the EN pad exposed in RST_BTN and solder it with a jumper cable, connect the other side of the jumper to the resistor, and solder it to the input capacitor, but not sure if it is a good idea.

[image: pcb]
[image: schematic]

Comment: Why do you think it's not a good idea? You need a pull-up and it does the job.

Comment: What are the pictures identifying?

Comment: @All - Please stop answering the question in comments. Using comments to answer is not allowed, as stated [here](/help/privileges/comment) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). Comments which do not follow those rules may be (and have been) flagged & deleted. Thanks.

Comment: This kind of rework is very common for prototypes. Just do it, see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice to use designators on your PCB. It would help us figure out who's who.

Pin #3 3V3 is just a few mm away. Can you not jam a resistor between pin 8 and 3? Of course it would need to be the right length. I would try that. It's supposed to be close to the pins.

Comment: I believe OP's current plan involves much larger pads of discrete components on the correct nets, and doesn't require nearly as strong soldering skills.